# How to use はるばる　/　はるばると in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

はるばる    - from afar; over a great distance; all the way

I'd greatly appreciate someone telling me what the と at the end of はるばる does to it's meaning, and if it affects the words' location in a sentence (I've seen it used at the beginning as well as the end of a sentence which has me confused!)

Any example uses much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something like `-ly` in English. It turns a word into an adverb. In  case of `はるばる`, it has a slight flavor of adverb from the beginning, so it may be used with or without `と`.

[image]

The word moving around is not directly due to `と`. Adverbs move around relatively freely.