# The meaning of と in 未来の国からはるばると

Tags: particle-と, adverbs

> 未来の国からはるばる**と**

This is the name of the first chapter of "Doraemon" (1).

What is the function of と in this case?

Apparently, it's not for quoting, and it doesn't seems to mean "if/when," "with" or "and..."

[Here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/how-to-use-%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-in-a-sentence) there is one answer in which they say that と　turns  a word into an adverb. But はるばる　is an adverb, isn't it?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24943/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36764/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of adding と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-%e3%81%a8)

Comment: At least it have to be there in this particular phrase to make はるばると a five-syllable (mora) prosodic unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Japanese dictionary says that はるばる is an adverb and sometimes is used with と. So you are right — the existence of と doesn’t change the grammatical role of はるばる. In fact, はるばる and はるばると are pretty much the same in terms of both usage and meaning.

As background, sometimes adverbs in Japanese are followed by と or に. (See [https://kotobank.jp/word/副詞-123983](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%89%AF%E8%A9%9E-123983); the 語形的分類 section in ニッポニカ explains this.)

Whether you add と or not depends on each person.

The following is just my opinion as a native speaker of Japanese. This is totally not a linguistic explanation and my major is not linguistics.

Ending sentences with an adverb *without* と or に seems unusual (though of course there are exceptions, but I think most of them are in the narration of TV shows or literature).

So without a と or に following the adverb at the end of the sentence, it makes me feel like the sentence has ended suddenly. Adding と at the end of the sentence tells readers that there is something omitted at the end of the sentence, for example “やってきた”.

The と helps me recognize that this sentence includes an omitted phrase at the end, and as a result I don’t feel that it ends suddenly, making it feel more natural (especially in a language like Japanese where omitting things is common).

Comment: Welcome! 英語訂正させていただきましたが、”wrong separation”のあたりの趣旨がよくわからなかったのでそのままにしました。

Comment: @DariusJahandarie ありがとうございます！ ！すいません、不確実なまま書いてしまったのであやふやになっていました。「と」の有無で何処までを一語として考えるかが変わるということを書きたかったんですが、はじめに同じ旨の事を書いているので、削除しました。