# Meaning of 「と」at the end of a sentence

Tags: particle-と, omission

The opening chapter of Doraemon is titled 「未来の国からはるばると」and I'm not sure what the 「と」means at the end of the sentence here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [usage of と in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/49003/usage-of-%e3%81%a8-in-this-sentence) The corresponding verb is something like やってきた, but it's omitted because はるばる(と) is almost always used with verbs related to "coming".

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69261/9831

Comment: Thank you, it looks like those two answer my question. For some reason, they did not appear in the search before submitting the question, or I must have missed it.

Comment: The answer is already provided here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69261/the-meaning-of-%e3%81%a8-in-%e6%9c%aa%e6%9d%a5%e3%81%ae%e5%9b%bd%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%af%e3%82%8b%e3%81%b0%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8 I think the other posts related to「と」made it difficult to see before submission, cheers all :)