Usage of particle と at the end of the sentence
first thing I apologize if I didn't find the answer in old posts, but there are so many of them that sometimes it's very difficult to find the correct answer!
I read the previous posts trying to give similar answer to my question and I understood them perfectly, but… I didn't find the correct answer for mine.
I found this phrase in the title of a chapter's manga:
未来の国からはるばると
Now, I am an absolute beginner, but from what I can tell this is not one of most obvious option possible for the usage of the particle at the end of the sentence. I am sure I am wrong, though, so I am asking you: what is the ending particle と doing at the end of the sentence? What does that mean? And what is the meaning of the sentence itself?
Thank you everybody for your help in advance!

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69261/9831
